# how to save image in subfolder (AnyName) in document in phone help me

Tags: iphone, ios-4.2

her i'm using this coding in my program

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *imageCacheDirPath = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image"];
NSString *imageCachePath = [imageCacheDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1.jpg"]; 
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:imageCachePath contents:dataObj attributes:nil];
```

what the problem in my coding.send some sample code .

Answer (score 10):

One potential problem is that 'Image' directory does not exist when you try to create file in it - it's required for createFileAtPath method to run properly. So check if Image folder exists and create it if required:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *imageCacheDirPath = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image"];
NSString *imageCachePath = [imageCacheDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1.jpg"]; 

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: imageCacheDirPath])
      [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:imageCacheDirPath 
                                withIntermediateDirectories:NO 
                                                 attributes:nil
                                                      error:NULL];

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:imageCachePath 
                                        contents:dataObj 
                                      attributes:nil];
```